# Isomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $K[x]/(f)\cong K[x]\bmod f\ $ [transport quotient ring structure to remainders]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Is there any good homomorphism $\phi$ I could use that graphs  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, that is one to one and onto. I'm not sure how to come up with one.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Divide $m$ by $n$ and take the remainder.

Comment: The most obvious one sends $x$ to $x$. What *precise* definition are you using for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ anyways?

Comment: How do you *define* $\mathbb{Z}_n$? If some professor told you that $\mathbb{Z}_n := \{0,1,\dotsc,n-1\}$, then good night ...

Comment: I thought  ${\mathbb Z}_n$ was defined as  ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$. But as a general strategy, if you are trying to prove that $G/N \cong H$, then look for a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$ with kenrel $N$ and use the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: @Derek Holt I was going to say the same thing you did.  I should not be surprised that the author of one of the texts I regularly use beat me to it.

Comment: @Alitzer: I couldn't help but notice you made a *huge* amount of edits in the past days, most of them very trivial like this one. It's generally accepted that these edits are okay, but in moderation. I encourage you to read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4966/unnecesarily-retagging-old-questions-that-get-bumped), [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10569/flagging-archaeological-edits) or [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/editing-binge-etiquette).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: Given an integer $m$, use the division algorithm to write $$m = nq + r$$ Define $\phi(m) = r \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and check the conditions for the first isomorphism theorem (or just show that $\phi$ works directly).

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $ $ Since in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ one may *divide with unique remainder* by $\,n,\,$ the coset  $\rm\: j +(n) \in \Bbb Z/n\:$ may be uniquely represented by its least  element $\ge 0,\,$ the remainder $\rm\:j\ mod\ n\, =\, j - kn.\:$ Thus the set $\,\Bbb Z_n =$  naturals $< n$ form a complete system of representatives of $\rm\,\Bbb Z/n.\,$ Hence we can represent $\rm\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ by these "normal forms", and pullback the ring operations to the normal form reps ([transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+transport+structure)), $ $ e.g. multiplication transported to $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ [becomes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910465/242) $\rm\,\ j * k\, :=\, j\:\!k\ mod\ n.\:$

The same *remainder representation* works for any *Euclidean domain* with *unique* remainders, i.e. any domain with a division algorithm with unique smaller remainder. For example, in a polynomial ring $\rm\,K[x]\,$ over a field $\rm\,K\,$ we can divide with *unique* remainder by any polynomial $\rm\,f,\,$ hence the coset  $\rm\: g +(f) \in K[x]/(f) = K[x]\bmod f\:$ may be uniquely represented by its least degree element, the remainder $\rm\:g\ mod\ f\, =\, g - hf.\:$ Therefore the polynomials of $ $ degree $\rm < deg\ f\,$ form a complete system of representatives of $\rm\,K[x]/(f).\,$ Thus we can represent the ring by these normal forms, and pullback ring operations to the normal form reps ([transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+transport+structure)), e.g. $\rm\: g * h := g\:\!h\ mod\ f.\:$

For example, [Hamilton's presentation of $\Bbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/23500) as pairs of reals is a special case of the above, namely $\:\Bbb R[i]\cong \rm\Bbb R[x]/(\color{#c00}{x^2\!+1}),\:$ with normal forms all linear polynomials $\rm\,(a,b) := {\rm\:a + bx }\:$ with the ring operations [transported to the pair normal form reps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145277/242), e.g. transported multiplication of pairs is

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm (a,\ b) &&\rm (c,\ d) &\!\!=&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd\ \ \ ,\ \ \   ad\!+\!bc)\\
\rm i.e.\  \bmod{\color{#c00}{\,x^2\!+1}}\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}\ \,\Rightarrow\,\  (a\! +\! b\color{#c00}x)&&\rm(c\! +\! d\color{#c00}{ x})\, &\!\!\!\rm\,\equiv&\rm (ac\!\color{#c00}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\, x\\\
\rm i.e.\quad\, (a\! +\! b{\it i}\,)&&\rm(c\! +\! d {\it i}\,)\, &\!\! =\,&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\,{\it i}\end{eqnarray}$

where $\,i := [x] := x+(x^2\!+\!1)\Bbb R[x]= $ coset (congruence class) of all $\,f\equiv x\pmod{\!x^2\!+\!1}$

There are *multidimensional* generalizations of the division algorithm (e.g. Grobner bases) which extend the above to certain multivariate polynomial rings $\rm\,R[x,y,z\ldots]/(f,g,h,\ldots).\:$

The above can be viewed as ring-theoretic special cases of very general methods in  [term rewriting systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_rewriting_system) for solving word problems in (quotient) equational algebras, e.g. the [Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%2DBendix_completion_algorithm) For more on the ring-theoretic perspective see George Bergman's classic paper: [The diamond lemma for ring theory, 1978.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90010-5) and its [errata and updates.](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/papers/updates/diamond.html) Chasing links to this will locate recent literature on these topics (generalizations of Grobner bases, etc).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910465/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145277/242).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for introductory remarks.

Answer (score 2):

First look at the construction of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Notice that the congruence class is defined as $[0]=\{\cdots,-2n, -n, 0, n, 2n,\cdots\}=n\Bbb Z$. Now because $n\Bbb Z$ is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, it does not matter what type of coset we construct. Now to construct the set of all cosets of $\Bbb Z$ modulo $n\Bbb Z$ we need to look at what the cosets look like. Now a coset of $m(n\Bbb Z)=\{m+a:a\in n\Bbb Z\}$. Now for $m(n\Bbb Z)$ we can compute it as $\{\cdots,-2n+m,-n+m,0+m,n+m,2n+m,\cdots\}=[m]$ notice how the coset is exactly the definition of a congruence class. Therefore the set of cosets $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is directly equal to $\{[0], [1],\cdots,[n-1]\}=\Bbb Z_n$ thus an isomorphism between the two is an automorphism. A trivial automorphism to choose would be the idenity automorphism $\imath:x\mapsto x$.