# $K \times K$ is a field iff $K$ satisfies that for all $a,b\in K$ that $a^2 + b^2 =0$ then $a=b=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have the following problem and I'm stuck in the second part:

Let $K$ be a field. We define in $K \times K$ the next operations:
$$(a, b) + (c, d) := (a + c, b + d)$$
$$(a, b) · (c, d) := (ac − bd, ad + bc)$$

1. Prove that $K\times K$ is a commutative and unitary ring with the given operations. **Done**
2. Prove that $K \times K$ is a field iff $K$ satisfies that for all $a,b\in K$ that $a^2 + b^2 =0$ then $a=b=0$.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the multiplicative identity is?

Comment: These are basically the operations you put on $\Bbb R^2$ to make it into $\Bbb C$. So, I guess you should try using the formula for the inverse in $\Bbb C$ and see what you get.

Comment: Hint: Think about how you take inverses in the complex numbers and how that relates to the condition here

Comment: Thanks for the answers, done!

Comment: Are you familiar with quotient rings such $\,K[x]/f(x) = K[x]\bmod f(x)?\, $ If so then first show that your ring is isomorphic to $\,K[x]/(x^2+1)\,$ and all follows easily and intuittively, e.g.[see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) If not, then you can instead use congruences to get the same effect - just as for integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$(a,b)\cdot(1,0)=(a,b)$, $(1,0)$ is the identity element of $K\times K$.

If $K\times K$ is field, suppose $(c,d)$ be the inverse of $(a,b)$. Then
$$
(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)=(1,0)
$$
Hence we have
$$ac-bd=1\tag1$$ 
$$ad+bc=0\tag2$$
 So there are 
$acb-b^2d=b$ from $(1)$ and $bc=-ad$ from $(2)$. Plug latter into former we have
$$
-a^2d-b^2d=-d(a^2+b^2)=b
$$
So if $a^2+b^2=0$, then $b=0$. And $a^2=0$ means $a=0$.

Conversely suppose for all $a,b\in K$ that $a^2 + b^2 =0$ then $a=b=0$. Then for $(a,b)\neq 0 \:(a,b\in K)$, there is $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$ for otherwise $(a,b)=(0,0)=0$. Thus $(a^2 + b^2)^{-1}$ exists in $K$. By solving $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$
c=a(a^2 + b^2)^{-1}, \quad d=-b(a^2 + b^2)^{-1}
$$
Hence $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(1,0)$ and $(c,d)$ is the inverse of $(a,b)$, i.e. $K\times K$ is field.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $K\times K$ is a field. If $(a,b)\ne0$, then also $(a,-b)\ne0$ and so
$$
(a,b)(a,-b)\ne0
$$
This proves one direction. For the converse, think to the complex numbers.