# Multiplication Operation in Complex Numbers (Introduction)?

Tags: complex-numbers

I just started a book on Complex Variables and there is something I cannot grasp:

The product of $z_1z_2$ is defined as follows: $z_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2,y_2)$

Now how did they manage to get this: $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2−y_1y_2, y_1x_2+x_1y_2)$.

Where did the minus even come from when doing the product? Can someone please explain?

Comment: This is how the product of two complex numbers is defined.

Comment: @MathLover Exactly and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the definition because this is as rudimentary as the textbook gets

Comment: This (Hamilton pair) representation is a special case of canonical remainder reps when computing modulo polynomials, here we are computing with polynomials modulo $\,\color{#c00}{x^2+1}\,$ where $\color{#c00}x$ represents $\color{#c00}i.\,$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: $\rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm (a,\ b) &&\rm (c,\ d) &\!\!=&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd,\quad\ \  ad\!+\!bc)\\
\rm i.e.\  \bmod{\color{#c00}{\,x^2\!+1}}\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}\ \,\Rightarrow\,\  (a\! +\! b\color{#c00}x)&&\rm(c\! +\! d\color{#c00}{ x})\, &\!\!\!\rm\,\equiv&\rm (ac\!\color{#c00}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\, x\\\
\rm i.e.\quad\, (a\! +\! b{\it\color{#c00} i}\,)&&\rm(c\! +\! d {\it\color{#c00} i}\,)\, &\!\! =\,&\rm (ac\!\color{#000}{\bf -}\!bd) + (ad\!+\!bc)\,{\it\color{#c00} i}\end{eqnarray}\ \ $

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/242) for the interesting historical background and motivation for Hamilton's pair construction of $\,\Bbb C.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You identify $(x,y)$ with $x+iy$, where $i$ have the property that $i^2=-1$. Then
$$(x,y)\cdot(z,w)=(x+iy)\cdot(z+iw)=xz+ixw+iyz+i^2yw=(xz-yw)+i(xw+yz)=(xz-yw,xw+yz)$$

Comment: The reason of why one take $i^2=-1$ is a little deep to answer here at this level

Comment: Well, $i^2=-1$ is just the property that defines the "$i$" in a complex number.

Comment: @JoséAlejandroAburtoAraneda Can you explain how you dropped the $+i$ at the end and simply wrote $xz-yw, xw+yz)$?

Comment: @Peter But answer why it's not simple...

Comment: @Mac only for use your notation. Corresponding every pair $(a,b)$ with $a+ib$, where $a,b$ are real numbers

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+bi)(c+di)=ac+adi+bci+bdi^2=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$$

So $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are transformed into $(ac-bd,ad+bc)$