# Because it is enough to calculate these values to find the quadratic residue $x^2 ≡ a (mod 13)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $m$ be a positive integer and $a$ any integer such that $(a, m) = 1$. Then $a$ is a quadratic residue of $m$ if the congruence $x^2 ≡ a (mod m)$ is solvable; otherwise, it is a quadratic nonresidue of $m$. For example if we want to find the quadratic residues of $m = 13$, we calculated $x^2 ≡ a (mod 13)$ with $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ and we will find that the quadratic residues are $a = 1, 3, 4, 9, 10,12$. If we continue calculating for $x=14$, $x=15$ and so on, we notice that the residuals will be repeated $a=1$, $a=4$ and so on,I wanted to know why this happens? Why is it enough to calculate the squares of numbers $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ only?

Comment: By the linked [Congruence Product or Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, x\equiv \bar x\Rightarrow x^2\equiv \bar x^2.\,$ More generally $\, x\equiv \bar x\Rightarrow f(x)\equiv f(\bar x)\,$ for any polynomial with integer coef's, by the Polynomial Congruence Rule, so we need only test for roots in a complete residue system, since every integer $x$  is congruence to an integer $\bar x$ in the complete residue system.

Comment: As an analogy, if we wish to test if a polynomial has a rational (fraction) root, then it suffices to test fractions in least terms, since every fraction is equivalent to one in least terms (like every integer $\bmod n$ is equivalent to its remainder $\bmod n,\,$ i.e. the remainder = least positive rep. may be viewed as its  "least terms" residue). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4042786/242) for more.