# Can the modular inverse be a negative value or only the positive ones are the allowed?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I searched for that and found opposite opinions some say that yes the negative are acceptable and others say that only the positive are the acceptable.
for example:
27^-1 (mod 392)
which of the following sets is true
{...,-813 ,-421,-29,363,755,1147,...}
{363,755,1147,...}

Comment: The people who say the negative aren't acceptable would probably also say that $755,1147,\dots$ are unacceptable as well.  The end result is... *whatever you want*.  That depends on how you are defining things and what is convenient for you.  It is perfectly true that $27\cdot (-421)\equiv 1\pmod{392}$ which should qualify it as being a modular inverse along with every other number from your first set.  It is also perfectly true that the only number $x$ in the range $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,391\}$ satisfying $27x\equiv 1\pmod{392}$ is $x=363$.

Comment: There are plenty of times where I would *prefer* working with negatives... for instance in noting that $(-1)^2 = 1$ is much faster than noting that $123478974\cdot 123478974\equiv 1\pmod{123478975}$

Comment: The modular inverse has representatives that are negative, very large and positive, etc. If you insist on choosing one in $0, ..., n - 1$, like the C-style operator $a \% n$, then you run into issues where $(-a) \% n\not = -(a \% n)$ and $(a + b) \% n \not = (a \% n) + (b \% n)$, etc. It's like insisting that an expression like $1/\sqrt{2}$ should be rewritten as $\sqrt{2}/2$; they're certainly equal, but what exactly does the latter get you for your arithmetic work?

Comment: JMoravitz
I got the point that you wanted to deliver, thanks

Comment: For arithmetic $\bmod n$ we can use any [complete system of residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4042786/242) as normal forms, i.e. any set of integers such that every integer is congruent to exactly one of them, e.g. any set of $\,n\,$ consecutive integers. If you seek *the* (normalized) modular inverse then you need to choose the element of the complete system that is congruent to it, e.g.  $3^{-1}\equiv -2\,$ in the [balanced system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1151595/242) $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\}\bmod 7.\,$ See the linked dupe for more.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  isn’t the purported duplicate about negative *moduli*, unlike this question?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Both negative moduli and remainders are discussed in the linked dupe.