# Is there a way to understand the group of polynomials mod an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

As a simple example:
$$
\mathbb{Z}[n]/ \langle n^2 - an - b \rangle
$$

We know this is simply all the linear expressions $\{cn+d \mid c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

But is there an explicit way to describe the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[n] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[n]/ \langle n^2 - an - b \rangle$?

E.g., take a poly $\displaystyle P(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \alpha_j n^j$

One can split this up in to even and odd powers and substitute in $n^2 = an + b$ to reduce it. This gives various constraints on $\alpha_k$ such as the obvious $\alpha_0 = d,\, \alpha_1 = c,\, \alpha_k = 0$ for $k>1$; there are more complex constrains though. I'm interested in the general representation of these complex constraints in the general case.

E.g., there are polynomials with an "infinite" number of non-zero coefficients that map to the a line(since that is all we are working with). E.g., what are all the polynomials that map to $3n + 4$?

I can't figure this out because when reducing $n^k = f(n)\cdot n^m,\; \deg(f(n)) = k-m$ one has ends up an infinite recursion:
$$
P(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \alpha_j n^j 
= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \alpha_{jk + i} n^{jk + i} 
= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \alpha_{jk + i} (f(n)\cdot n^m)^j n^i$$

And one is left trying unwind an infinite number of nested $n^k$ values. Of course at each stage we can a new set of constrains on the coefficients but one can't generalize the results this way it seems.

So, simply, I just want to explicitly construct/parameterize the equivalence classes of a homomorphism on a polynomial ring. In this case I'm ok with just using a simple ideal.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you are asking, but in $\mathbb Z[n]$ there are no "infinite polynomials". Maybe you meant to say $\mathbb Z[[n]]/<n^2-an-b>$?

Comment: Notation: use `\langle n^2 - an - b \rangle` for better ideal angle brackets: $\langle n^2 - an - b \rangle$

Comment: $g(\bar n) = h(\bar n)\,$ in $\Bbb Z[\bar n] = \Bbb Z[n]/f(n)\iff g(x)\equiv h(x)\pmod{\!f(x)},\,$ i.e. $\,f\mid g-h.\,$ For simplicity we usually choose to work with the least degree reps, i.e. reduce $\,g\,$ to its congruent remainder $\,g\bmod f\,$ having degree $< \deg f,\,$ see the [remainder represnetation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242). $\ \ $

Comment: Note: prior comment assumes as in OP that $\,f(x)\,$ is monic (lead coef is a unit $= \pm1),\,$ so that the [division (with rem)  $\ g\div f\,$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) for all $\,g\in \Bbb Z[x].\ \ $