# on the representation of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Considered an irreducible polynomial with coefficient over a field $\Bbb K$ $ (f(x)\in\Bbb K[x]$) and $\deg f(x)=n$ ; in my textbook is written that: $$ {\Bbb K[x]\over \langle f(x)\rangle} = \{a_0+a_1x+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\langle f(x)\rangle \mid a_i\in\Bbb K\} $$
Is it true? and if it's how can I prove this ?(I apologize if the question may seem silly)

Comment: This follows immediately by **transporting** the quotient ring structure to the coset least-degree reps, i.e. using the remainder $\,g\bmod f\,$  as a normal form for the coset $\,g+(f),\,$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials of degree less than that of $f$ give an irredundant collection of representatives for the quotient, yes. Maybe a nod to the division algorithm for polynomials in one variable with coefficients in a field?

Comment: Thank you for the kindness of responding. I get it

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Paul Garrett's answer, note that $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is generated by the set $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ as a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. Via the division algorithm for polynomials over a field, every polynomial $g \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ can be written as
$$
g = qf + r
$$
with $r\equiv 0$ or $\deg r < \deg f$. Passing to the quotient, it follows that $g+(f) = r+(f)$, and $r$ can be expressed uniquely as a $\mathbb{K}$-linear combination of the set $\{1,x,...,x^{n-1}\}$.