# What are $0$ and $1$, the elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? How do they relate to $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition, finite-fields

I often see field $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}=\{0,1\}$. Without other indication we might see elements of field $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbf{Z}$. Operations such as $2+1=3=1$ are also given as examples:

[image]

[Source](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/coding/Overheads/08_crcs.pdf).

I understand this field is the one defining the sum modulo-2 (and the Boolean addition provided we associate False/True to $0$/$1$), and in $\mathbf {Z}$, $3$ modulo $2= 1$ but I've some difficulty to fully understand these statements:

- $2+1=3=1$ seems incorrect since the addition associated with field $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$ (the modulo/boolean addition) is used on elements $2$ and $1$, but $2$ is not in $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$.
- $3=1$ seems to be used (approximately) to indicate there is a correspondence between $3 \in \mathbf {Z}$ and $1 \in \mathbf {Z} / \mathbf {2Z}$.

On the other hand, my understanding is elements of field $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$, denoted $0$ and $1$ are actually classes of elements of group $\mathbf{Z}$:

- $2+1$ should rather be written $0 + 1 = 1$, as $0$ (of $\mathbf{Z} / \mathbf{2Z}$) is the class corresponding to number $2$ (of $\mathbf{Z}$), and $1$ is the class corresponding to number $1$.

Can someone provide a rigorous explanation with a more accurate wording on what is the field $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$, how is is related to $\mathbf{Z}$  and what is the nature of its elements?

Comment: The elements are *residue classes*. Basically, $\overline{0}$ is the set of all even integers, and $\overline{1}$ is the set of all odd integers.

Comment: [Wikipedia on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) may be the best WP source. Here it is (in my opinion) either off topic, or duplicate zillion times over.

Comment: Also [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)) for the field with $2$ elements.

Comment: Do you know about quotient rings?

Comment: @Temoi: No, only about [quotient of vector spaces.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf#page=114)

Comment: The correct setting to talk rigorously about $\mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z} $ is that of quotient rings. Intuitively it's the same thing as quotient vector spaces but with other operations to be preserved. Namely in your case you have a ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ and you take the quotient classes modulo $2\mathbb{Z}$ (you can see that the set of quotient classes has a natural ring structure with the operation induced by the ring structure of $\mathbb{Z}$.  (not posting this as an answer because this is just to give an idea. If someone wants to espand, feel free to do it)

Comment: @Temoi: Thanks that's the kind of clue I'm looking for.

Comment: You may find the wikipedia page about [quotient rings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) useful

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) in the linked dupe, it arises by *transporting* the qutient ring structures to remainder reps of the cosets, i.e. we rep $\,a+(n)\in \Bbb Z/(n)\,$ by the remainder $\,\ a\bmod n (= $ least nonnegative elt of the coset).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$ is a field represented by the two equivalence classes of integers modulo 2. We take ${0},{1}$ as representatives of the two classes given by the partition which splits the integers between even and odd, where 0 is in the class of all even integers, 1 is in the class of all odd integers.

Then, you can check , that addition and multiplication are well-defined (which they are), and that it satisfies all the field axioms. As you said , Edit: Credit to Mark S below  "2 is not in that set, but the equivalence class modulo 2, [2]=[0] is in that set" , which is what $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{2Z}$ represents: equivalence classes under mod 2.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my view. I was confused by $2+1=1$, with a left side in Z, and a right side in Z/2Z. The right side should be $=3 (mod 2)$ which is also in Z (or both sides should be in Z/2Z). While the meaning is clear for seasoned mathematicians who do the mapping, it's confusing for learners.

Comment: @mins Personally, I would prefer to say something like "2 means 1+1 in whatever system in question we're looking at. So in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $2+1=1$ is true and involves no integers, but instead means that $(1+1)+1=1$."

Comment: @J.Dmaths, I feel your writing of $2(mod2)\equiv0$ mixes together the operator usage (common in computer science) and the relation usage (more common in math) of "mod" in a way I find confusing and likely in conflict with what mathematicians intend.

Comment: How should I edit it to make it clearer? @MarkS.

Comment: @MarkS.: "*in $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$, $2+1=1$ is true*". I'm confused by the fact the operator associated with $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$ is used on elements which don't belong to $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$ (2 is not in $\mathbb {Z} / \mathbb {2Z}$). I may be wrong, and that's the whole point of my question, but this operator is not defined for 2+1.

Comment: @mins I am disagreeing with your assumption that the symbol "2" (or "1", for that matter) can refer only to the integer 2. Rather, these are *context-dependent* symbols. For instance, as documented at [the Wikipedia page for identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Definitions), "1" is often used for the multiplicative identity, no matter what context (e.g. which ring) we are in. Similarly, in a context where the multiplicative identity can be added to itself, "2" denotes "1+1" where addition and the identity "1" are determined from context (e.g. the standard ones in Z/2Z).

Comment: @J.Dmaths It depends what precisely you would like to convey. For instance, you could write something like "2 is not in that set, but the equivalence class modulo 2, [2]=[0] is in that set". I might still argue with you on that point, but that phrasing would at least be clear and in line with mathematical usage.

Comment: Ah, ok I understand what you mean now about the notation : Yes , that part is slightly confusing , I will edit it to how you have said!